# ECS | Get metadata of the service my app is running on

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-ecs

we have an app written in typescript that runs in a container in an ECS service.
I want to collect data about the task definition and the service it is running on in runtime.
For example, get the task definition number and ARN.
And then finally write a log with these details (with logger).

How do I collect data about the service on run time through the app that is running on the service? What is the best way to fulfill these requirements?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your app needs to query the ECS Task metadata endpoint.

If you are deploying to EC2 instances, read [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-metadata-endpoint.html).

If you are deploying to Fargate, read [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-metadata-endpoint.html).

---

If you are doing this just for logging, the default ECS logging to CloudWatch Logs includes the task ID in the log stream name, and you would usually specify the service name as part of the log group name.